# Disenable, to extract data from SimpleXMLElement object

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I'm extracting data from an xml file by using **xpath** in **php** so my code looks like this:

```
xml = simplexml_load_file("CCV.xml");

foreach ($xml->xpath('./section[@label="Education"]/section[@label="Degrees"]') as $degrees) {
    var_dump($degrees);
}
```

Before switching to this kind of code above, I was using XPath->query (path) which works well to return the data I needed. But now I'm really stuck with this sort of the array structure. I was looking for another post with the same problem, but the structure of the array is more simple and comprehensive. So how can I return the value **Doctorate** in this case):

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[5]
  public '@attributes' => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string 'aee5a225a504442fb83f716235cfb587' (length=32)
      'label' => string 'Degrees' (length=7)
      'recordId' => string '5b6f8e21156d44fa87cff8271b8bae84' (length=32)
  public 'field' => 
    array (size=13)
      0 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[8]
          public '@attributes' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          public 'lov' => string 'Doctorate' (length=9)
      1 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[9]
          public '@attributes' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          public 'value' => string 'Ph. D.' (length=6)
          public 'bilingual' => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[27]
              ...
      2 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[10]
          public '@attributes' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          public 'value' => string 'Software Engineering' (length=20)
          public 'bilingual' => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[28]
              ...
      3 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[11]
          public '@attributes' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          public 'value' => string 'Approximate Graph Matching for Software Engineering' (length=51)
      4 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[12]
          public '@attributes' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          public 'refTable' => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[29]
              ...
      5 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[13]
          public '@attributes' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          public 'value' => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[34]
              ...
      6 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[14]
          public '@attributes' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
      7 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[15]
          public '@attributes' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
      8 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[16]
          public '@attributes' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          public 'lov' => string 'Completed' (length=9)
      9 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[17]
          public '@attributes' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          public 'value' => string '2007/9' (length=6)
      10 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[18]
          public '@attributes' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          public 'value' => string '2011/8' (length=6)
      11 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[19]
          public '@attributes' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          public 'value' => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[35]
              ...
      12 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[20]
          public '@attributes' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
  public 'section' => 
    array (size=6)
      0 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[21]
          public '@attributes' => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          public 'field' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
      1 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[22]
          public '@attributes' => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          public 'field' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
      2 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[23]
          public '@attributes' => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          public 'field' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
      3 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[24]
          public '@attributes' => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          public 'field' => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
      4 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[25]
          public '@attributes' => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          public 'field' => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
      5 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[26]
          public '@attributes' => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          public 'field' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
```

Xml file:

```
<section id="aee5a225a504442fb83f716235cfb587" label="Degrees" recordId="5b6f8e21156d44fa87cff8271b8bae84">
            <field id="a83a0af883924c57bb66107cc32b6d5e" label="Degree Type">
                <lov id="00000000000000000000000000000073">Doctorate</lov>
            </field>
            <field id="7df537009941493789a32bcae3499909" label="Degree Name">
                <value type="Bilingual">Ph. D.</value>
                <bilingual>
                    <english>Ph. D.</english>
                </bilingual>
            </field>
            <field id="35696972e69541dd86a80521d3737b26" label="Specialization">
                <value type="Bilingual">Software Engineering</value>
                <bilingual>
                    <english>Software Engineering</english>
                </bilingual>
            </field>
            <field id="ca55badff5c1483cbb1c69495a22d0af" label="Thesis Title">
                <value type="String">Approximate Graph Matching for Software Engineering</value>
            </field>
            <field id="6e225f28f003427aa79aa68ff0aa3865" label="Organization">
                <refTable label="Organization" refValueId="00000000000000000000011930246375">
                    <linkedWith label="Country" refOrLovId="00000000000000000000000000002000" value="Canada"/>
                    <linkedWith label="Subdivision" refOrLovId="00000000000000000000000000100000" value="Quebec"/>
                    <linkedWith label="Organization Type" refOrLovId="00000000000000000000000000030000" value="Academic"/>
                    <linkedWith label="Organization" refOrLovId="ee597e9073b6479b94f903ca08f81903" value="École Polytechnique de Montréal"/>
                </refTable>
            </field>
            <field id="020ec1f40f3d4065bf5424f77209b8e4" label="Other Organization">
                <value type="String"/>
            </field>
            <field id="f1a127d96eb64b1e8776023106ac4a00" label="Other Organization Type"/>
            <field id="fc5c85c9557441399dba19033697d56d" label="Other Organization Location"/>
            <field id="c42a1deb6fe046dfa5502169032760de" label="Degree Status">
                <lov id="00000000000000000000000000000068">Completed</lov>
            </field>
            <field id="337ee6b2606c4c899f0e0c4ec3bd6ec2" label="Degree Start Date">
                <value format="yyyy/MM" type="YearMonth">2007/9</value>
            </field>
            <field id="4b818aef68a84743b19149d376032afb" label="Degree Received Date">
                <value format="yyyy/MM" type="YearMonth">2011/8</value>
            </field>
            <field id="91b70ad64b6843fdaae1e94282bc77f0" label="Degree Expected Date">
                <value format="yyyy/MM" type="YearMonth"/>
            </field>
            <field id="b04a491dc6ea4fc99e2453dbfb834965" label="Transferred to PhD without completing Masters?"/>
            <section id="447d27e319c94c2dbb661959c7c40c97" label="Areas of Research" recordId="4025fa6db2ce411cacbdc64b653ede39">
                <field id="a8b0b7584b454b3c96fc34882a7bae12" label="Order">
                    <value type="Number">1</value>
                </field>
                <field id="e7677e7cec974b3d81196938648b731f" label="Area of Research">
                    <refTable label="Area of Research" refValueId="00000000000000000000063990580350">
                        <linkedWith label="Sector of Research" refOrLovId="00000000000000000000000100003800" value="Natural Sciences and Engineering"/>
                        <linkedWith label="Field" refOrLovId="28b7043d4ec74915a90ee44bbf5ec71f" value="Abstract Structures"/>
                        <linkedWith label="Subfield" refOrLovId="1bb709ee05854387a897b8a17cfd3f0e" value="Computer Sciences and Mathematical Tools"/>
                        <linkedWith label="Area" refOrLovId="75f906df893642f895b9203370e0b9a9" value="Software (Tools)"/>
                    </refTable>
                </field>
            </section>
            <section id="447d27e319c94c2dbb661959c7c40c97" label="Areas of Research" recordId="daab01e02aae4a00b6802f32bb3b2b26">
                <field id="a8b0b7584b454b3c96fc34882a7bae12" label="Order">
                    <value type="Number">2</value>
                </field>
                <field id="e7677e7cec974b3d81196938648b731f" label="Area of Research">
                    <refTable label="Area of Research" refValueId="00000000000000000000080370827290">
                        <linkedWith label="Sector of Research" refOrLovId="00000000000000000000000100003800" value="Natural Sciences and Engineering"/>
                        <linkedWith label="Field" refOrLovId="28b7043d4ec74915a90ee44bbf5ec71f" value="Abstract Structures"/>
                        <linkedWith label="Subfield" refOrLovId="1bb709ee05854387a897b8a17cfd3f0e" value="Computer Sciences and Mathematical Tools"/>
                        <linkedWith label="Area" refOrLovId="75f906df893642f895b9203370e0b9a9" value="Optimization, Control and Operations Research"/>
                    </refTable>
                </field>
            </section>
            <section id="42e0ec8b7946411f9b2a0f2093ce2f1e" label="Research Disciplines" recordId="abc11eb9dd034caeabada014f79c48d6">
                <field id="7f0f0c79f847413cbdefbd52dee958dd" label="Order">
                    <value type="Number">1</value>
                </field>
                <field id="c437657271cf457fa2b516dbd1d57efc" label="Research Discipline">
                    <refTable label="Research Discipline" refValueId="00000000000000000000082120706250">
                        <linkedWith label="Sector of Discipline" refOrLovId="00000000000000000000000100003700" value="Natural Sciences and Engineering"/>
                        <linkedWith label="Field" refOrLovId="1add935c1fbc44ec96e9edfe94ad6863" value="Engineering"/>
                        <linkedWith label="Discipline" refOrLovId="4ac3aff1a8314560b7b7e048099e7996" value="Computer Engineering and Software Engineering"/>
                    </refTable>
                </field>
            </section>
            <section id="49eb8b6f4d0c4e3aa68dbe242bdecfb4" label="Supervisors" recordId="6e6c66c147b5411e975f7264cb43999e">
                <field id="c5d78ee68528412d892acc849851dbe6" label="Supervisor Name">
                    <value type="String">Philippe Galinier</value>
                </field>
                <field id="93f1886a6ace43659d519b628e9f026e" label="Start Date">
                    <value format="yyyy/MM" type="YearMonth">2007/9</value>
                </field>
                <field id="7dd6df1257ef461f806b5e644741e1a2" label="End Date">
                    <value format="yyyy/MM" type="YearMonth">2011/8</value>
                </field>
            </section>
            <section id="49eb8b6f4d0c4e3aa68dbe242bdecfb4" label="Supervisors" recordId="c4bd2c87a6154afd93b0254147975ece">
                <field id="c5d78ee68528412d892acc849851dbe6" label="Supervisor Name">
                    <value type="String">Giulio Antoniol</value>
                </field>
                <field id="93f1886a6ace43659d519b628e9f026e" label="Start Date">
                    <value format="yyyy/MM" type="YearMonth">2007/9</value>
                </field>
                <field id="7dd6df1257ef461f806b5e644741e1a2" label="End Date">
                    <value format="yyyy/MM" type="YearMonth">2011/8</value>
                </field>
            </section>
            <section id="14f15c08598c4baa911697a16157d75a" label="Fields of Application" recordId="a5c79fac596441e9ba0a19bd25148e42">
                <field id="4e269294415249079731231561dfec8b" label="Order">
                    <value type="Number">1</value>
                </field>
                <field id="99e0bcb3d8344827915f282ec3ca7e3a" label="Field of Application">
                    <refTable label="Field of Application" refValueId="00000000000000000000000908181810">
                        <linkedWith label="Field of Application" refOrLovId="00000000000000000000000100003900" value="Science and Technologies"/>
                        <linkedWith label="Subfield" refOrLovId="bb37c5edd6464aa3a99abcaaf1251bed" value="Communication and Information Technologies"/>
                    </refTable>
                </field>
            </section>
        </section>
```

Comment: relevant part of input shoud be helpful

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean, you want to see the xml file.

Comment: yes, but the part which is selected by the xpath query is enough

Comment: I added the xml file part.

Comment: `foreach ($value->field as $f) { if ('Degree Type'==$f->attributes()['label']){$x=$f->lov;break;}}` I guess

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work. It's a good idea too

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cbb72ebe873c929821a2

Comment: Thank you. I will use this structure for extracting the other data. Great joob

Comment: For a question, pleas do not copy and paste from your live code. Instead create a self-containing example from scratch that contains as little code as necessary to illustrate your issue. Also not only say you searched, but provide reference to existing Q&A material here on site and explain why it didn't help you.

Comment: And btw., there is no array in your question, that is a SimpleXMLElement and the var_dump is only writing array there because it is faked. For a SimpleXMLElement always refer to the XML itself, not the var_dump (this is why cske has asked for the XML for example). Basic SimpleXML usage is also documented here: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: And out of curiosity because you wrote about it in your question: When you used  XPath->query (path) how did this looks like and why didn't you use it any longer when it worked for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As accepted in comments

```
foreach ($xml->field as $f) { 
      $a=$f->attributes();
      if ('Degree Type'==$a['label']){
            $x=$f->lov;break;
      }
}
```

Comment: This answer lacks an explanation what the code is supposed to do in context of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The code above work great with **simplexml_load_string()**. But in my case it does not work and i got x variable undefined.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("CCV.xml");

// foreach ($xml->xpath('./section[@label="Education"]/section[@label="Degrees"]') as $details) {
        foreach ($xml->field as $details) {
                $a = $details->attributes();
                    if ('Degree Type'== $a['label']){
                        $x=$details->lov;
                        break;
                }

        }

    var_export($x);
```

I have 3 degrees. So I would like to show them (Doctorate ,Master and Bachelor)

Comment: This is not an answer. Sounds more like you wanted to do an edit of your question? If so please edit your question to improve it.